# Undefined variable: _SESION

Tags: php, session, variables, upload, undefined

I create project uploading form with file and image upload...
when i submit i got error Undefined variable: _SESION

html

```
<form id="wts_form" role="form" data-toggle="validator" novalidate="" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="PHP/projectuploader.php" method="post">
```

php code in another file

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESION);
if(isset($_POST["wts_name"]))
{ ................


}
```

I made many of these things, but this only happens here....

Comment: 2 S's in `_SESSION`

Comment: its `$_SESSION` not `$_SESION` , you have a spelling mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake in

```
var_dump($_SESION);
```

It should be `var_dump($_SESSION)`. Take note of the two `S`'s in `$_SESSION`.